# Angularjs - Service is re-instanciated when changing html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to set up a little scenario here where I would display a research page with all the related Inputs, proceed to the search, get the results then display the results on a new page.
So my architecture would be the following:

- Angular Module (Controllers + Services)
- search.html
- results.html

One of the service would be responsible for launching the research and getting the results, and I would like to use this service to pass data from one controller to the other controller when changing page. I see every where that service is a singleton and that once instantiated, it should not be instantiated again.

However when changing page, my services is reinstanciated (all the js file are reloaded) and when I try to get the results from the service, I have a pretty :
 " Variable Results undefined "

My code would look like somethings like this:

### Angularjs

```
angular
    .module('myapp.search_controller.services')
    .factory('SearchFares', SearchFares)
    .controller('SearchController', SearchController);
    .controller('ResultsController', ResultsController);

SearchFares.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http', 'SortFares'];
SearchController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'SearchFares'];
ResultsController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'SearchFares'];

function SearchFares($cookies, $http) {
    var results = [];

    var SearchFares = {
        CheapestDests: CheapestDests,
        GetResults: GetResults,
    };
    return SearchFares;

    function SetResults (params) {
         if (params) { 
             results = params;
             return true;
         } 
    }

    function GetResults () {
         return results;
    }

    function CheapestDests(params) {
        // do whatever you want with params then set results
        if (SetResults(params)) {
            window.location = '/results.html';
        }
    };
}

function SearchController($location, $scope, SearchFares) {
    // mapped to search.html with the ng-controller directive
    // blablabla do something with the scope - then call the service 
    // On click, launch the search
    $scope.search = search;
    function search() {
        SearchFares.CheapestDests({something: 'somewhere'});
    }
}

function ResultsController ($location, $scope, SearchFares) {
    // mapped to results.html with the ng-controller directive
    $scope.results = SearchFares.GetResults();
    // blablabla process the data
}
```

### HTML - search.html

```
<div ng-cloak class="row">
    <form role="form" ng-submit="search()" ng-controller="SearchController" >
      <!-- Fill up the input then push the bouton search
      --- -->
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/search_controller.module.js' %}"></script>
```

### HTML - results.html

```
<div ng-cloak class="row">
    <div" ng-controller="ResultsController" >
      <!-- Do what you need to do with $scope.results but here it is undefined 
      --- -->
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/search_controller.module.js' %}"></script>
```

I can't avoid the service to be reinstanciated and then var results to be set at undefined (var results = {}). Is there a way, using a service, to pass data between controllers when changing page location?

Merci :)

Aldeen

Answer (score 1):

You are switching pages using window.location="/whatever". This actually reloads all the services and factories to initial state when you do this as in effect this is similar to a page reload.

If you want to get results in another page you should use ui-router or ngRoute or something similar and just switch the view so the factory doesn't get reloaded.

I see you have angular-routes script already added in your module. So just convert search and results into two ng-views and switch between them using

```
$location.path('/whatever').
```

That way your foctory wont reload when you switch views

Comment: Thanks Nijeesh for the info and leading me into the right direction. I haven't succeeded yet, because I encounter routing issue with my templates (I am also using Django so it's kinda messy). I will let you know once it's solved.

Comment: I have eventually solved my routing issue, and tried what you suggest, and it works fine :) - Thanks a lot! It also allowed me to identify some errors that might have bothered me later!